# CGI.unescape and CGI.unescapeHTML don't do anything

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a string that I receive as a response to a get request

```
{&quot;revision&quot;=&gt;&quot;r2407&quot;, &quot;full_version&quot;=&gt;&quot;2.5 [r2407]&quot;, &quot;full_name&quot;=&gt;&quot; [r2407]&quot;, &quot;version&quot;=&gt;&quot;2.5&quot;}
```

In a js file:

```
$('.output').text('<%=CGI.unescape(@response.to_s)%>')
```

I still get the same string with `&quot`'s and stuff. I also tried JS unescape() and it didn't do anything too. What's wrong?

Comment: That might be a stupid question, but does your file have an .erb extension?

Comment: @BroiSatse yes, it's js.erb

Answer (score 0):

[`CGI.escape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-escape) and [`CGI.unescape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-unescape) is to handle URL-encoded string.

```
CGI.escape('&')
# => "%26"
CGI.unescape('%26')
# => "&"
```

Use [`CGI::unescape_html`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-unescapeHTML) instead:

```
CGI.unescape_html('&gt;')
# => ">"

body = '{&quot;revision&quot;=&gt;&quot;r2407&quot;, &quot;full_version&quot;=&gt;&quot;2.5 [r2407]&quot;, &quot;full_name&quot;=&gt;&quot; [r2407]&quot;, &quot;version&quot;=&gt;&quot;2.5&quot;}'
CGI.unescape_html(body)
# => {"revision"=>"r2407", "full_version"=>"2.5 [r2407]", "full_name"=>" [r2407]", "version"=>"2.5"}
```

Comment: Tried it. Still no effect. There is actually that line in the controller: `response.body = CGI.unescape_html(response.body)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you first need to unescape the HTML from response using [`CGI.unescape_html`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-unescape_html), then escape it for JavaScript with [`j`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript):

```
$('.output').text('<%=j CGI.unescape_html(@response.to_s)%>')
```